# HTTP works with Nginx and Node.js but HTTPS dosent

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, socket.io, nginx-reverse-proxy

nginx config

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.my.domain my.domain;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:6969;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

index.js (http)

```
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);

// Store connected clients
const clients = [];

// WebSocket event handling
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // Add new client to the list
  clients.push(socket);

  // Handle incoming messages
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    // Broadcast message to all connected clients
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

  // Handle disconnection
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    // Remove client from the list
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
  });
});

// Define route handler for the root route ("/")
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});

// Start the server
server.listen(6969, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 6969');
});
```

imdex.js (https)

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/only-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/cloudflare_root.pem')
}, app);
const io = socketIO(server);

// Store connected clients
const clients = [];

// WebSocket event handling
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // Add new client to the list
  clients.push(socket);

  // Handle incoming messages
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    // Broadcast message to all connected clients
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

  // Handle disconnection
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    // Remove client from the list
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
  });
});

// Define route handler for the root route ("/")
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});

// Start the server
server.listen(6969, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 6969');
});
```

The index.js http version works just fine and provides "Hello, world!" output but the https version
only gives a "502 Bad gateway" error

*Note that key.pem is a bundle file with a private key and Cloudflare root ca*
*So I created only-key.pem which only contains the private key*

I just want https connection and to display "Hello world"

Comment: so what happens when you restart nginx? Does it complain that there are config errors? Also, if you're making nginx handle the SSL part, you don't make node also do that, you just proxy through to it. Client asks for https, nginx negotiates that for you and proxies your plain node http traffic. It'll be https when it leaves nginx.

Comment: Nginx -t output:
```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```
ok well I am just gonna use the HTTP version and block the 6969 port for any external IPs

Comment: Yep, that's the standard configuration: a redirect from http to https, and a port forward from 443 to your internal port, which should already not be accessible because nginx only allows requests through that it has rules for.